# Aggregation GROUP BY bottleneck

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, execution-plan

I have a performance bottleneck with a `SELECT GROUP BY` operation.

## Schema

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [InverterData](
    [InverterID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,    
    [ValueA] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ValueB] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_e149e28f-5754-4229-be01-65fafeebce16] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [TimeStamp] DESC,
        [InverterID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
    , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

and a `Index` like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TimeStamp_Power-NonClusteredIndex] ON [dbo].[InverterData]
(
    [InverterID] ASC,
    [TimeStamp] ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(   
    [ValueA],
    [ValueB]
)
```

The `[InverterData]` table as has following storage stats:

- Data space: 26,901.86 MB
- Row count: 131,827,749
- Partitioned: true
- Partition count: 62

## Usage

With my descripted schema (one plus some extra table that are not important for my question) I can run super fast queries like this:

```
SELECT [TimeStamp], [ValueA], [ValueB]

FROM [InverterData]

JOIN [Inverter] ON [Inverter].[ID] = [InverterData].[InverterID]
JOIN [DataLogger] ON [DataLogger].[ID] = [Inverter].[DataLoggerID]

WHERE [DataLogger].[ProjectID] = 20686
 AND [InverterData].[TimeStamp] >= '20160108'   
 AND [InverterData].[TimeStamp] < '20160109'
```

**Excecution timespan:** 178ms

**Excecution plan:**

[image]

## Problem

I now want to make a `SELECT GROUP BY` by [InverterID] and 15 minute interval of [TimeStamp].

Somethink like this:

```
SELECT [InverterID]
 , DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [TimeStamp] ) / 15 * 15, 0) AS [TimeStamp]
 , SUM([ValueA]), SUM([ValueB])

FROM [InverterData]

JOIN [Inverter] ON [Inverter].[ID] = [InverterData].[InverterID]
JOIN [DataLogger] ON [DataLogger].[ID] = [Inverter].[DataLoggerID]

WHERE [DataLogger].[ProjectID] = 20686
 AND [InverterData].[TimeStamp] >= '20160107'
 AND [InverterData].[TimeStamp] < '20160108'

GROUP BY
 [InverterID], DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [InverterData].[TimeStamp] ) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

**Excecution timespan:** 4637ms

**Excecution plan:**

[image]

## Attempts

I think it can be related to the necessary `Sort` operation here:

[image]

As far as I know it is possible to avoid this `SORT` by creating a matching indexer. But I don't know how to do this with my 15 minute interval grouping.

## Question

As you can see the excecution timespan of the `SELECT GROUP BY` is massivly longer. But I don't know where and how to avoid the bottleneck!?

#### Update 1 (related to @Max Vernon answer)

If it is possible ide like to have a faster solution where I can flexible change the interval (for example 10, 15 or 6o minutes). So without calculated columns.

Comment: have you tried using `UNION ALL` to see if it gives your any improvement ? The table NC index that you have given has different columns. Can you post the other table DDL so we can recreate the problem and help you ?

Comment: Please add the requested details, including partitioning definition, to your question to avoid wasting peoples' time with an incomplete problem statement. Does 10, 15, 60 minute intervals represent a complete set of possibilities? Is the requested date range always small?

Comment: Partition definition plays absolutely no role in my question. It don't has impact on the time taking sort step. I think I wrote clearly that I'm searching for a flexible search statement and that 10, 15 and 60 are only examples. No the requested date range is also undefined. I don't see that as "timewasting" only because I dont say that variables are variable.

Comment: But it might very well play a role in the answer, so please include it. Max's great answer was basically invalidated by your saying the intervals should be variable - and you'd already thought of a computed column solution - after he had posted it. Neither of these things were mentioned in the question, so yes, that time was wasted. Before "update 1" the question mentions 15 minute intervals specifically multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a calculated column to the table and build an index from the calculation.

For instance, the table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InverterData
(
     InverterID bigint NOT NULL
    , TS datetime NOT NULL    
    , ValueA decimal(18, 2) NULL
    , ValueB decimal(18, 2) NULL
    , TS15 AS (DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TS ) / 15 * 15, 0))
    , CONSTRAINT PK_InverterData PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        TS DESC,
        InverterID ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        )
);
```

I've modified the name of the `TimeStamp` column to `TS` since `TimeStamp` is a reserved word.

After looking at Paul's comment; I think a good index might be:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_InverterData_ID_TS151 
ON dbo.InverterData (TS15, InverterID);
```

If you change the `WHERE` clause to operate on the indexed timestamp column, I get no sort in the plan.  I figure the change to the `where` clause is likely not a problem since you appear to be selecting on whole days.

```
SELECT InverterData.InverterID
    , InverterData.TS15
FROM InverterData
WHERE InverterData.TS15 >= '20140107'
    AND InverterData.TS15 < '20160108'
GROUP BY InverterData.InverterID
    , InverterData.TS15
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Granted, I've not included the other tables in my example, since you have not provided those details.

The plan for the query above is, with 100,000 rows in my sample table:

[image]

Having said all that, without the actual table definitions, including the partitioning scheme, etc, it is difficult to tell how well this will actually work for you.

Since adding a (non-persisted) computed column is a meta-data only operation, modifying the table should be nearly instantaneous.  You'd still likely want to do this when you know there are no other transactions (or as few as possible) occurring so the required schema lock (although very short lived) won't block.  The DDL to modify the table is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.InverterData
ADD TS15 AS (DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TS ) / 15 * 15, 0));
```

Comment: Hi @Max, I already thought about this. But I want a solution where I can flexible change the interval. 10, 15 o6 minute for example. Sorry I made it more clear in my question.

Comment: @SteffenMangold - you cannot "have your cake and eat it too".  The only way to get the query to avoid a sort is to use the correct index, as I've identified in my answer.  The "correct index" in this case happens to be one that contains the TimeStamp stored in the interval your query will use.  You could add multiple indexes to support a limited number of preset intervals.